# Removed DLL causing runtime error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5

I have an ASP.NET web application built in visual studio 2013, .NET framework 4.5.1.  The app used to reference a 3rd party dll, but I have refactored the program so it is no longer needed.  I have removed the dll from the references and confirmed it is not being used anywhere in the solution.  The solution builds just fine.

The problem comes when I try to run it.  I get the familiar ASP white screen of death indicating that it cannot find the Namespace.  The screen shows that the error occurs in a file in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ that seems to be generated at runtime.  I don't know why or how this file is generated, or why it is still referencing the removed dll.

The Error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Web' does not exist in the namespace 'Telecom' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

Line 17: public class ProfileCommon : System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase {
Line 18:     
Line 19:     public virtual Telecom.Web.Modules.Common.Code.Preferences Preferences {
Line 20:         get {
Line 21:             return ((Telecom.Web.Modules.Common.Code.Preferences (this.GetPropertyValue("Preferences")));

Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\sso\8bcf3ae8\e33c1692\App_Code.zywjwlv-.0.cs    Line: 19
```

Comment: just remove temporary files

Comment: @Alex I tried that, they are regenerated every time it runs.

Comment: yes, they are regenerated, but new

Comment: The error happens each time they are regenerated.

Comment: and you're cleaned and rebuilded solution?

Comment: Have you tried grepping your entire codebase directory structure for the reference's name in all filetypes? Sounds like it's still being referenced somewhere.

Comment: I don't think it'll be this, but have you also tried an iisreset?

Comment: Presuming you're using IIS of course